# Install obsoleting package without removing obsoleted package

Tags: linux, redhat, yum, rhel6

Is there any way to install an obsoleting package alongside the package it obsoletes using yum? There are a couple conflicting files but the packages can coexist just fine with the latest version of these files.

A normal installation of the obsoleting package removes the obsoleted package:

```
# rpm -qa | grep tc-server
vfabric-tc-server-standard-2.9.7-RELEASE.noarch

# yum -y install pivotal-tc-server-standard vfabric-tc-server-standard
---> Package pivotal-tc-server-standard.noarch 0:3.2.1-RELEASE will be obsoleting
---> Package vfabric-tc-server-standard.noarch 0:2.9.7-RELEASE will be obsoleted
...
================================================================================
 Package                     Arch    Version           Repository          Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 pivotal-tc-server-standard  noarch  3.2.1-RELEASE     pivotal-app-suite   34 M
     replacing  vfabric-tc-server-standard.noarch 2.9.7-RELEASE
...
Running Transaction
  Installing : pivotal-tc-server-standard-3.2.1-RELEASE.noarch              1/2
  Erasing    : vfabric-tc-server-standard-2.9.7-RELEASE.noarch              2/2

Installed:
  pivotal-tc-server-standard.noarch 0:3.2.1-RELEASE

Replaced:
  vfabric-tc-server-standard.noarch 0:2.9.7-RELEASE

# rpm -qa | grep tc-server
pivotal-tc-server-standard-3.2.1-RELEASE.noarch
```

I tried:

```
yum -y --setopt=obsoletes=0 install pivotal-tc-server-standard vfabric-tc-server-standard

yum -y install pivotal-tc-server-standard --exclude=vfabric-tc-server-standard
```

Which don't seem to do anything different from a normal install.

I also tried:

```
# yum install pivotal-tc-server-standard --setopt=protected_packages=vfabric-tc-server-standard
---> Package pivotal-tc-server-standard.noarch 0:3.2.1-RELEASE will be obsoleting
---> Package vfabric-tc-server-standard.noarch 0:2.9.7-RELEASE will be obsoleted
Error: Trying to remove "vfabric-tc-server-standard", which is protected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this using yum yet. Here's what does work:

```
# yum -y install yum-utils
# yumdownloader pivotal-tc-server-standard
# rpm -i --replacefiles pivotal-tc-server-standard-X.X.X-RELEASE.noarch.rpm

# rpm -qa | grep tc-server
vfabric-tc-server-standard-2.9.7-RELEASE.noarch
pivotal-tc-server-standard-3.2.1-RELEASE.noarch
```